# Pygame: Surface.set_at() Transparent Color

Tags: python, pygame

In pygame there is a function for surfaces that set color of an image at a certain pixel in that image. The code is:

```
pygame.Surface.set((x,y),Color)
```

However, when I attempt to give it a transparent color it doesn't apply the transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doc [pygame.Surface.set_at](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at)

> If the Surface does not have per pixel alphas, the alpha value is
>   ignored.

-

see [pygame.Surface.convert_alpha](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)